# Rails run a method with the browser closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to do something I am not sure is possible in Rails.

I want to execute a method on a button click and then have the method run continuously even with the browser closed until a terminate button is pressed that will stop it.

essentially I am looking how to code:

1) a wrapper that runs a method periodically (every hour)

2) a way to execute the code even with the browser closed

If its relevant I am planning to host on AWS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running ruby on rails function without opening the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175258/running-ruby-on-rails-function-without-opening-the-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cron Jobs for this purpose. Refer https://launchschool.com/blog/cron-jobs-and-rails

Cron is a piece of software written for *nix-type operating systems to help with the scheduling of recurring tasks.

You can start editing your cron tasks using the crontab command:

```
crontab -e
```

Once you’re in the editor, you can start creating and editing cron tasks. To schedule a task, you need to define when the task will run, then define the command to trigger that task.Once you have your schedule defined, you can follow it with any valid bash command.

To run an existing rake task, you can change your directory to your application root, then call the rake task, it would look some thing like this:

```
0 0 * * * cd /my/app/root && /path/to/bundle exec rake some_task
```

Comment: Just to add: there are a ton of gems that help you administer cron jobs. [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is a popular choice.

Comment: You probably want to expand your answer a bit, as it's likely to be flagged as a "link only" answer, which is discouraged here because links may change or be removed, rendering your answer useless. Provide an example of how the asker can set up a simple cron job that fits his parameters.

Comment: Great thanks and cheers for the link to the gem - that will definitely be a help for me for the first time using Cron

Comment: After reviewing the documentation I am not sure how to do the final part where I can turn the recurring task on and off from the view.

Is it possible to activate and deactivate Cron from a button in a rails view?